# How to return null for a character returning method in java?

Tags: java, methods, null, char, return

```
import java.util.*;

char[] characterArray1 = {'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'};
char[] characterArray2 = {'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E', 'T'};
System.out.println(FRC(characterArray2));

public static char FRC(char[] array) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for(char character: array) {
                if(hashMap.containsKey(character)) {
                        return character;
                }else {
                        hashMap.put(character, 1);
                }
        }return null
}
```

characterArray1 is able to return character 'B' as it is the first recurring character

So how am I able to return null from a character returning method when I use characterArray2 as the argument?

Comment: If you were able to return null (you can't), you would need to test whether the method returned null. In the same way, you can test whether it returned 0 (i.e. '\0')

Comment: Why use a `Map` if you're going to return immediately upon finding the duplicate? Just use a `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return `null`, you need to make the return type the primitive wrapper type, `Character`.

Also, there is no obvious need to use a `Map` here: use a `Set`, and use the return value of `Set.add` as an indicator that the character was seen before:

```
public static Character FRC(char[] array) {
  Set<Character> seen = new HashSet<>();
  for (Character c : array) {
    if (!seen.add(c)) {
      return c;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Character` which wraps a value of the primitive type `char` in an object.

```java
public static Character FRC(char[] array) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for(char character: array) {
                if(hashMap.containsKey(character)) {
                        return character;
                }else {
                        hashMap.put(character, 1);
                }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69327494/642706) by Andy Turner said, use a `Set` for tracking individual objects rather than a `Map` for pairs of objects.

## Code point

The `char` type (and its wrapper class `Character`) is legacy, and is essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, it is not capable of representing most characters.

Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

```java
public static String firstRecurringCharacter ( List < String > inputs )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( inputs );
    Set < Integer > seen = new HashSet <>();
    for ( String s : inputs )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( s , "Input of list of String objects contained a null." );
        if ( s.length() != 1) throw new IllegalStateException( "Input of list of String objects contained an element with other than one character." );
        if ( ! seen.add( s.codePointAt( 0 ) ) )
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage.

```java
List < String > inputX = List.of( "D" , "B" , "C" , "A" , "B" , "A" );
List < String > inputY = List.of( "D" , "B" , "C" , "A" , "E" , "T" );

System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputX ) );
System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputY ) );
```

When run.

> B
>
> null

## `Optional`

Returning null as a legitimate value is problematic. In such a case, use an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) wrapper.

```java
public static Optional < String > firstRecurringCharacter ( List < String > inputs )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( inputs );
    Set < Integer > seen = new HashSet <>();
    for ( String s : inputs )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( s , "Input of list of String objects contained a null." );
        if ( s.length() != 1 ) throw new IllegalStateException( "Input of list of String objects contained an element with other than one character." );
        if ( ! seen.add( s.codePointAt( 0 ) ) )
        {
            return Optional.of( s );
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Usage.

```java
List < String > inputX = List.of( "D" , "B" , "C" , "A" , "B" , "A" );
List < String > inputY = List.of( "D" , "B" , "C" , "A" , "E" , "T" );

System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputX ).orElse( "No recurring characters." ) );
System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputY ).orElse( "No recurring characters." ) );
```

When run.

> B
>
> No recurring characters.

## `String` rather than list of characters

Of course in the code above you need not use code point integers given an input of strings with a single character each. You could just make a `Set< String >` rather than `Set< Integer >` for code points.

Where the code points are useful is in tearing apart a string of multiple characters. So the calling programmer need not pass a collection of single-character strings. Instead, a `String` of several characters could be passed.

```java
public static Optional < String > firstRecurringCharacter ( String input )
{
    Objects.requireNonNull( input );
    int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
    Set < Integer > seen = new HashSet <>();
    for ( int codePoint : codePoints )
    {
        if ( ! seen.add( codePoint ) )
        {
            return Optional.of( Character.toString( codePoint ) );
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Usage.

```java
String inputX = "DBCABA";
String inputY = "DBCAET";
String inputZ = "ABCABC";

System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputX ).orElse( "No recurring characters." ) );
System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputY ).orElse( "No recurring characters." ) );
System.out.println( App5.firstRecurringCharacter( inputZ ).orElse( "No recurring characters." ) );
```

When run.

> B
>
> No recurring characters.